# Variable not changing from its initial value when it outputs in the result

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried and tried at finding why the variable OdEv is not changing from its initial value. It should change depending on whether x is odd or even in the function workingOdd(), but it just stays at the initial placeholder value of 'T'.

Code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background: grey; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
<script>
    
  function closebox() {
  document.getElementById("box").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("closeboxbutton").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("openboxbutton").style.visibility="visible";
  }
  
    function openbox() {
    document.getElementById("box").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("closeboxbutton").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("openboxbutton").style.visibility="hidden";
  }
   

  
  </script>

<div style="background:black;color:white;padding:10px;text-align:left; height:20px;">
        <div id="togglestakesshow"><button style="float:left; width:220px;" onclick="showstakes()">SHOW STAKES STRUCTURE</button></div>
    <div id="togglestakeshide"><button style="float:left; width:100px;" onclick="hidestakes()">HIDE STAKES STRUCTURE</button></div>
    <div id="openboxbutton"><button style="display:inline-block;" onclick="openbox()">OPEN INPUT BOX</button></div>
    <div id="closeboxbutton"><button style="display:inline-block;" onclick="closebox()">CLOSE INPUT BOX</button></div>
    <div id="bankrollwindow" style="margin-top: -4px; width:70px; text-align:center; float:right; padding:5px; color:black; background:white; display:inline-block;">£</div>
    <div style="float:right; margin-right:10px;">BANKROLL</div>
    
    </div>
<div id="stakespanel">CONTENT OF STAKES</div>
    
<div id="results" style="border:5px solid white; height:730px; overflow:scroll;background:white;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="betsdiv" style="  position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);height:160px; width:1200px; border: 5px solid white; background: green; ">
    
      <div id="toprow">
           
           <div class="toprowbets">1st 12</div>
           <div class="toprowbets">2nd 12</div>
           <div class="toprowbets">3rd 12</div>
           
               <div style="clear:both;"></div>
               
            <div class="bottomrowbets">1-18</div>
            <div class="bottomrowbets">EVEN</div>
            <div class="bottomrowbets">RED</div>
            <div class="bottomrowbets">BLACK</div>
            <div class="bottomrowbets">ODD</div>
            <div class="bottomrowbets">19-36</div>
            
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>    
    

  
  
  
  <div id="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <div id="modal-content">
      <p>Select a number between 0 and 36:</p>
      <div id="numberButtons"></div>
      <button id="close-button" onclick="closebox()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <style>
  
  
  .toprowbets {
  height:75px; 
  line-height:75px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:390px; 
  border: 5px solid white;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:600; 
  color:white;
    }
  
   .bottomrowbets {
  height:75px;
  line-height:75px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:190px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight:600; 
  color:white;
  }
 
 
 #openboxbutton
 { visibility: hidden; 
 display: inline-block; 
 position: relative; 
 top: -6px  }
 
  #closeboxbutton
 { visibility: visible; 
 display: inline-block; 
 position: relative; 
 top: -6px; 
 left: -113px; }

#togglestakesshow {
   font-size:10px;
   width: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline-block;
   }
   
#togglestakeshide {
   font-size:10px;
   width: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline-block;
   }   
  
#stakespanel {
   overflow: hidden; 
   height:0px;
   border:1px solid black;
   background: white;
   }
  
    /* The modal background */
    #modal {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    /* The modal content */
   #modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 18%;
  border: 3px solid black; 
  
  #box {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-top: -150px; /* half of the box's height */
        margin-left: -150px; /* half of the box's width */
        visibility: visible;
      }
  
}

#stakesbox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 800px;
        height: 200px;
        z-index: 2;
        margin-top: -150px; /* half of the box's height */
        margin-left: -150px; /* half of the box's width */
        visibility: visible;
        border: 2px solid black;
        Background-color:white;
      }




    /* The close button */
    #close-button {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #numberButtons button {
      color: white;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      font-size:30px;
  font-weight:600;
    }
    
    #modal.inactive{
  opacity: 0.2;
}

  </style>
  <script>
  
  var odEv="T";
var txtOdEv="#33ccff";
  
     
  var bankRoll = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter your starting bankroll:"));
  if(isNaN(bankRoll)){
    bankRoll = parseFloat(prompt("Invalid input. Please enter a valid number for your starting bankroll:"));
  }
  

  
bankRoll = bankRoll.toFixed(2);

updateBankroll()
  
    var spinNumber=0;
    
    var x=0;
    
    
    
    var backline="";
    
    
    var isDragging = false;
    var currentX;
    var currentY;
    var initialX;
    var initialY;
    var xOffset = 0;
    var yOffset = 0;

    const modalContent = document.querySelector("#modal-content");

    modalContent.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
    modalContent.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd);
    modalContent.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);

    function dragStart(e) {
      initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
      initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;

      if (e.target === modalContent) {
        isDragging = true;
      }
    }

    let inactivityTimeout;

function dragEnd(e) {
  initialX = currentX;
  initialY = currentY;

  isDragging = false;
  clearTimeout(inactivityTimeout);
  inactivityTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    modal.classList.add("inactive")
  }, 15000)
}


function drag(e) {
    if (e.buttons === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
    currentY = e.clientY - initialY;

    xOffset = currentX;
    yOffset = currentY;

    setTranslate(currentX, currentY, modalContent);
    clearTimeout(inactivityTimeout);
    modal.classList.remove("inactive")
    }
}

function updateBankroll() {
     document.getElementById("bankrollwindow").innerHTML = "£" + bankRoll;
}

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
      el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }

function roulette(number) {
      // Determine the color of the number
      var color;
      if (number === 0) {
        color = "Green";
      } else if (number === 1 || number === 3 || number === 5 || number === 7 || number === 9 || number === 12 || number === 14 || number === 16 || number === 18 || number === 19 || number === 21 || number === 23 || number === 25 || number === 27 || number === 30 || number === 32 || number === 34 || number === 36) {
        color = "Red";
      } else {
        color = "Black";
      }

      // Map the color names to CSS color values
      if (color === "Green") {
        return "rgb(0, 128, 0)";
      } else if (color === "Red") {
        return "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
      } else {
        return "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
      }
 }



function workingOdd() {
  var odEv;
  if (x % 2 === 0) {
    odEv = 'Ev';
  } else {
    odEv = 'Od';
  }
  // the rest of the function
}



function backgroundline() {
       if (spinNumber % 2 === 0) {
        backline="#D3D3D3"
      } else {
       backline="#E5E4E2";
      }
    }
    



function spin(number) {
  // Determine the color of the number
  
  var color = roulette(number);
  spinNumber= spinNumber+1;
  
  bankRoll=bankRoll-10.25;
  backgroundline();
  
  
   // Display the result
  var resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
  var resultHTML = `${number}`;
  
  
  
  resultHTML = `<div style="background: ${backline}; vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:0px; border-bottom: 1px solid white;">
  
  <div style="padding:5px; display: inline-block; background: yellow; color:black;vertical-align:middle; width:30px; text-align:right;">${spinNumber}</div>
  
  
  
  <div style="margin: 0 10px; display:inline-block; width: 80px; text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">£${bankRoll}</div>
  
  <div style="color: white; display: inline-block; width:30px;font-size: 25px; font-weight:600; height:30px; text-align:center; line-height: 30px; vertical-align:middle; background-color: ${color}; ">${number}</div>
  
   <div style="color: white; display: inline-block; width:30px;font-size: 25px; font-weight:600; height:30px; text-align:center; line-height: 30px; vertical-align:middle; background-color: ${txtOdEv}; ">${odEv}</div>
   
  </div>`;
  
  
  resultsDiv.innerHTML += resultHTML;
  
  document.getElementById('results').scrollTop = document.getElementById('results').scrollHeight;
     

  
    updateBankroll();
  
}
// Set up the buttons
for (let i = 0; i <= 36; i++) {
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = i;
  button.style.backgroundColor = roulette(i);
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    x = i;
    workingOdd();
    spin(i);
    });
  document.getElementById("numberButtons").appendChild(button);
}

function closeModal() {
  // Get the modal element
  var modal = document.getElementById("box");

  // Remove the modal element from the DOM
  modal.remove();
}

function showstakes() {
  // show
document.getElementById("stakespanel").style.height="300px";
document.getElementById("togglestakesshow").style.width="0px";
document.getElementById("togglestakeshide").style.width="150px";};

function hidestakes() {
  // hide
document.getElementById("stakespanel").style.height="0px";
document.getElementById("togglestakeshide").style.width="0px";
document.getElementById("togglestakesshow").style.width="150px";};





  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried lots of different ways to get this working, and have done some testing, and it appears that the value does change at a certain moment in the script, but when the result is outputted when the number buttons are pressed it is always still as 'T'.

"${odEv}"

Comment: could you reduce the code to a minimal example? I am not willing to read that.
Please remove styling and unnecessary parts.

Comment: A simple error - inside your `function workingOdd()` you are redeclaring the `odEv`. Just remove the `var odEv;` from your function, since your `odEv` is a global variable. Be sure to check your console as well - while testing your code, I noticed a reference error - `modal is not defined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `odEv` is a global variable, but then you declare it as a local variable (this becomes a separate variable with no relation to the original). The local variable is the one you're changing.

Remove the `var odEv;` from `workingOdd()`, then it will operate on the global variable.

```
function workingOdd() {
  // var odEv; // remove this
  if (x % 2 === 0) {
    odEv = 'Ev';
  } else {
    odEv = 'Od';
  }
  // the rest of the function
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, it has worked! I thought I had tried that!